# Text classification with torchnlp

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, pytorch, text-classification

i'm trying to build a neural network using **pytorch-nlp** (https://pytorchnlp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
My intent is to build a network like this:

- Embedding layer (uses pytorch standard layer and `from_pretrained` method)
- Encoder with LSTM (also uses standard `nn.LSTM`)
- Attention mechanism (uses `torchnlp.nn.Attention`)
- Decoder siwth LSTM (as encoder)
- Linear layer standard

I'm encountering a major p*roblem with the dimensions* of the input sentences (each word is a vector) but most importantly with the *attention layer* : I don't know how to declare it because i need the exact dimensions of the output from the encoder, but the sequences have varying dimensions (corresponding to the fact that sentences have different number of words).

I've tried to look at `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence` and `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence` since they're supported by LSTM, but i cannot find the solution.

Can anyone help me?

### EDIT

I thought about padding all sequences to a specific dimension, but I don't want to truncate longer sequences because I want to keep all the information.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with padding all sequences to a specific dimension. You will have to pick a dimension that is larger than "most" of your sentences but you will need to cutoff some sentences. This [blog article](https://medium.com/dissecting-bert/dissecting-bert-part-1-d3c3d495cdb3) should help.